# I want to write CHAPTER title in a fancy style

Tags: chapters

Here are the packages I used. Could you please let me know what I should do to write "CHAPTER 1" in a fancy style like written on page 28 in this link
ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf ?

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small,font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt

\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
```

Comment: This is a guide for the memoir class. If you want exactly that style then you should use memoir.

Comment: you mean I should change only the \documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}?

Comment: And you should use memoir's commands to apply this style (you linked to). Memoir has a great documentation.